# PHP session, multiple pages linking to one page

Tags: php, variables, session, overwrite

Okay, so I just noticed this issue.  There has to be a way around it.

Example...
On page A.php and on page B.php, there is a link to page ALPHABET.php.  ALPHABET.php receives specified variable values depending on which page is the referrer.

All pages involved have session_start(); at the beginning.

Page A.php has:

```
           <?php 
                $_SESSION['name'] = "John";
           ?>
```

Page B.php has:

```
           <?php 
                $_SESSION['name'] = "Jane";
           ?>
```

Page ALPHABET.php has:

```
           <?php
                $personName = $_SESSION['name'];
                echo "Hello, I am ".$personName;
           ?>
```

I decided not to close the session in ALPHABET.php, because I want the information to still load correctly if some refreshes the page.  If session were closed, then $_SESSION['name'] wouldn't exist or have a value.

This all worked fine and good, until I loaded both pages, A.php and B.php, at the same time (via new tab).  I noticed that the when I click the link to ALPHABET.php on either of these pages, it doesn't always take the session info from the page that was the referrer.  I noted that in this situation, the last page that loaded will have its information displayed in ALPHABET.php, instead of the page from which I clicked the link.

i.e.  I load both pages up.  First A.php and then I open B.php in a new tab.  I click on the ALPHABET.php link inside of A.php.  ALPHABET.php loads B.php's information.  I assume this is because B.php was the last page to load and therefore it overwrote all session data from A.php and replaced it with its own.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: To expand more, my example of A.php and B.php is a watered down example of my issue.  In reality, I have over 100 pages like A.php and B.php, and growing.  This is why A.php and B.php are passing the same variable to ALPHABET.php, so alphabet can just take the info and plug it into the generic variable and display it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP sessions are stored in cookies, which are shared between all tabs of a browser. E.G. there's not a good way to get around this simply by using vanilla sessions.

One effective way, however, would be to store the information in two separate variables and then put a GET request that is specific to each referrer.

E.g.

A.php

```
$_SESSION["A_name"] = "John";
?>

<a href="Alphabet.php?ref=A">Click</a>
```

B.php

```
$_SESSION["B_name"] = "Jane";
?>

<a href="Alphabet.php?ref=B">Click</a>
```

Alphabet.php

```
if($_GET["ref"] == "A")
    echo $_SESSION["A_name"];
else if($_GET["ref"] == "B")
    echo $_SESSION["B_name"];
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  Unfortunate, its not practical for my situation.  I'll expand more.  My example of A.php and B.php was a watered down example of my issue.  In reality, I have over 100 pages like A.php and B.php, and growing.  So, its not very practical to use an If statement like that in the ALPHABET.php page.