# Getting data based on which row chosen using session

Tags: php, mysql, session, html-table

How do I get the particular data(link url) depending on the row in which I pressed the button "edit" to be used on the edit.php page. As for now I'm using session but the only data( link url) I got is the "bing.com" although I pressed the button on the "google.com" row.

[image]

**PHP**

```
<?php
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$_SESSION["shorturl"]=$rows['shorturl];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['shorturl']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['phonenumber']?></td>
<td><button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php';">Edit</button><button onclick="location.href = 'show.php';">Show</button><button onclick="location.href = 'delete.php';">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: you could use a 'id' in query string, like e.g.: `<button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php?id="<?= $rows['id']; ?>';"`. You would pick up the 'id' of the record you'd like to edit in edit.php with $_GET['id'].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session, multiple pages linking to one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338262/php-session-multiple-pages-linking-to-one-page)

Answer (score 2):

You can send record id as request parameter in your edit/show/delete. Make the changes in your code as Follow:

```
<?php
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$_SESSION["shorturl"]=$rows['shorturl];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['shorturl']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['phonenumber']?></td>
<td><button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php?id=' . echo $rows['id'] . ';">Edit</button><button onclick="location.href = 'show.php?id=' . echo $rows['id'] . ';">Show</button><button onclick="location.href = 'delete.php?id=' . echo $rows['id'] . ';">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

While fetching data in particular file, just check if `id` is set on that file. If `ID` is set, then do your operations on record `ID` which we have sent in request parameter.

Note: Session will not work for your question as it holds data till session ends.

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar ive change the code to : <button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php',id=<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">Edit</button> ,,, but it only gets the bing.com id now

Comment: Can you please show your edit.php? I guess you are accessing session variable there, so you are getting bing.com only

Comment: actually, how do i use the $rows['id] in the edit.php page? because if i use $id=$rows['id'] in the edit.php, the rows would be an undefined variable.

Comment: You should use $id = $_GET['id']

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the session-variable every time you run through the loop here:

```
$_SESSION["shorturl"]=$rows['shorturl];
```

Maybe u can try to use a GET-Param instead

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php?shorturl=<?php echo urlencode($rows['shorturl']); ?>';">Edit</button>
```

Then retrive the shorturl on the edit.php site like this:

```
$shorturl = $_GET['shorturl'];
```